# How long does variable assignment take?

Tags: c#, performance, variables, variable-assignment, assign

I've frequently come across code that made liberal use of variables like `var self = this;` so their code would look nicer. **While I don't think assignments like these are going to be significant at all in any piece of code,** I've always wondered how long an assignment like above would take.

With that said: **How long does it take, assuming it isn't optimized away?** How do the times compare between different languages- e.g. C#, Java, and C++? Common value types (including pointers)? 32 / 64-bit architectures?

---

EDIT: Erased the part about "noticeable difference". I meant that part as a side-question, but many people have seen that and started downvoting me for premature optimization (in spite of me highlighting the bottleneck part in bold).

Comment: Apparently this kind of thing takes apprximately no time and the general advice is not to worry about it. But you could always test it for yourself with a big loop and an accurate timer.

Comment: @TomChantler The problem is with a big loop, checking if `i < len` and `i++` would probably take a lot more time than the assignment itself.

Comment: "could it make a noticeable difference" very, very unlikely.  Unless your program does virtually nothing else other than variable assignments, other operations are going to be massively more significant that assignments.  The only way to know for certain it to write a representative program and test it both ways.

Comment: In many cases, random "pointless" assignments like this would probably be optimized out

Comment: @JamesKo That's my point - the "meat" of a program will take orders of magnitude longer than variable assignments, so micro-optimizing them will not make a significant difference in overall performance.

Comment: Yes, local variable lookups are usually faster than those that require you to go higher up in the scope. I’m not sure if that’s true for `this` in C# though, and regardless of that, no, you should not worry about that *ever*. Write clear code that gives away your intention. Don’t try to micro optimize things that won’t be a performance bottleneck anyway.

Comment: Assignments like `var self = this` are going to be trivial, since `this` is a reference type (when working with classes), it will just set another pointer to the object. The interesting thing may come in when using `this` inside a struct, since an assignment will cause a copy, modifying `self` will not be reflected in `this` so may be a very difficult to find bug. Creating a new pointer to an existing object is very cheap, since it does not require object construction or memory allocation.

Comment: @RonBeyer and D Stanley, yes, clearly assignments like those are trivial. I would like to know how much *time* they will take.

Comment: This is a fairly meaningless question because "an assignment" could result in very different code depending on the context. It's not so simple as "an assignment executes in x nanoseconds", such a statement would be wrong for any x.

Comment: "time" is an arbitrary unit on computers, given different processors, architectures, speed, system load, etc. You could measure in cycles for a more empirical view, but even that is difficult to quantify. What takes 0.0001ms on my computer, may take 1ms on an old Pentium II.

Comment: @harold and Ron Beyer: Yes, I realized that; assignments are different for value / reference types, depend on the architecture of the machine, and many other factors. I'll try to update my question to reflect that.

Comment: Anyway perhaps this is what you want to know: on a Haswell, a copy between two registers is handled by the register renamer and appears to have a latency of zero. That doesn't mean it's free, it still has a finite throughput and so on. But a dependent instruction won't wait for the copy. Of course realistically, there wouldn't even *be* any copy, but you said "assuming it isn't optimized away"..

Comment: The "time" is going to come down to how "optimized" the compiler is (note: not compiler optimizations, talking about the ability for the compiler to generate machine code). After that you are going to have to break out an architecture book and count instruction times for each assembly level instruction. Really when you get down to it you are talking in ns, and at that point its impossible to time accurately. So the only way is to count processor instruction times. No way to do that without looking at the machine code the compiler generates. Create a test in each language and get an arch book.

Comment: @RonBeyer Don't forget time that the code may spend waiting for other processes in a multi-threaded system.  But you're right the actual time spent is infinitesimal.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
var self = this;
```

Isn't creating a new instance of object 'this', but it is referencing a pointer to the object 'this'. At the machine level there is only one pointer since the C# compiler optimizes these types of reference out. So the "how long it takes" is actually zero.

So, why do 'this'? Because it makes code easier to read.

Comment: I realize that assignment copies the pointer, and I asked specifically if the C# compiler has something on its hands that it can't optimize out (such as `i = 3`).

Comment: I answered the question you posted and the answer is 0. I don't understand your new question.